# Is the universal $G$-bundle functorial in $G$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, topological-groups, classifying-spaces

We know that the classifying space construction $G \mapsto BG$
gives a functor from topological groups to spaces.

I was wondering if the whole construction of the universal bundle is functorial in $G$?
I.e., given a topological group homomorphism $f : G\rightarrow G'$
we get a commutative diagram
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
EG @>{Ef}>> EG' \\
@VVV @VVV \\
BG @>{Bf}>> BG'
\end{CD}$$
where the vertical maps are the universal bundles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To a $G$-set $X$, one can define a category with objects the elements of $X$ and $\operatorname{Hom}(x,y)=\{g \in G | gx=y\}$. This construction has the property that it is functorial with respect to maps of $G$-sets. When $X=G$ we call this category $EG$, and when $X=*$ we call this category $BG$. There is a unique map of $G$-sets $G \rightarrow *$, and so it induces a map of categories $EG \rightarrow BG$.

The realization of this map $EG \rightarrow BG$ is a fibration with fiber $G$. Since $EG$ has a terminal object, that makes its realization $|EG|$ contractible, implying that $|BG|$ is a $BG$. This construction clearly is functorial with respect to group homomorphisms $G \rightarrow H$

Comment: Thank you! I was wondering, where specifically do the constructions in your answer make use of the topology on ?

Comment: The construction also works for topological groups $G$, one must just topologize the objects and arrows in the above constructions.

Comment: I see, thanks! Would you be able to suggest a reference that goes into detail about the topological aspects of the above constructions, especially the particular topologies used?

Comment: Check out https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/action+groupoid